# Function is working in some cases but fails when longest sub-string "reuses" a character

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a function called lengthOfLongestSubstring and its job is to find the longest substring without any repeated characters. For the most part, it works, but when it gets an input like "dvdf" it prints out 2 (rather than 3) and gives [dv, df] when it should be [d, vdf].

So, I first go through the string and see if there are any unique characters. If there are, I append it to the ans variable. (I think this is the part that needs some fixing). If there is a duplicate, I store it in the substrings linked list and reset the ans variable to the duplicate string.

Once the whole string has been traversed, I find the longest substring and return its length.

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {    
    String ans = "";
    int len = 0;
    LinkedList<String> substrings = new LinkedList<String>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (!ans.contains("" + s.charAt(i))) {
        ans += s.charAt(i);
      } else {
        substrings.add(ans);
        ans = "" + s.charAt(i);
      }
    }

    substrings.add(ans); // add last seen substring into the linked list

    for (int i = 0; i < substrings.size(); i++) {
      if (substrings.get(i).length() >= len)
        len = substrings.get(i).length();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(substrings.toArray()));

    return len;


}
```

Here are some test results:

```
//correct
lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb") -> 3 ( [abc, abc, b, b]) 

lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew") -> 3 ([pw, wke, w]).

lengthOfLongestSubstring("ABDEFGABEF"); -> 6 ([ABDEFG, ABEF]) 

// wrong
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("acadf")); -> 3, ([ac, adf]) *should be 4, with the linked list being [a, cadf]
```

Any suggestions to fix this? Do I have to redo all my logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that on the line `ans = "" + s.charAt(i)`, you're assuming that the next string you want to record starts at the current character.  What you should be setting `ans` to is the previous `ans` _without_ its first character, plus `charAt(i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is mistakenly assuming that when you find a repeated character, the next candidate substring starts at the repeated character. That is not true, it starts right after the original character.

Example: If string is `"abcXdefXghiXjkl"`, there are 3 candidate substrings: `"abcXdef"`, `"defXghi"`, and `"ghiXjkl"`.

As you can see, the candidate substrings ends before a repeating character and starts after a repeating character (and begin and end of string).

So, when you find a repeating character, the position of the previous instance of that character is needed to determine the start of the next substring candidate.

The easiest way to handle that, is to build a `Map` of character to last seen position. That will also perform faster than continually performing substring searches to check for repeating character, like the question code and the other answers are doing.

Something like this:

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charPos = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> candidates = new ArrayList<>();
    int start = 0, maxLen = 0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < s.length(); idx++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(idx);
        Integer preIdx = charPos.get(ch);
        if (preIdx != null && preIdx >= start) { // found repeat
            if (idx - start > maxLen) {
                candidates.clear();
                maxLen = idx - start;
            }
            if (idx - start == maxLen)
                candidates.add(s.substring(start, idx));
            start = preIdx + 1;
        }
        charPos.put(ch, idx);
    }
    if (s.length() - start > maxLen)
        maxLen = s.length() - start;
    if (s.length() - start == maxLen)
        candidates.add(s.substring(start));
    System.out.print(candidates + ": ");
    return maxLen;
}
```

The `candidates` is only there for debugging purposes, and is not needed, so without that, the code is somewhat simpler:

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charPos = new HashMap<>();
    int start = 0, maxLen = 0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < s.length(); idx++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(idx);
        Integer preIdx = charPos.get(ch);
        if (preIdx != null && preIdx >= start) { // found repeat
            if (idx - start > maxLen)
                maxLen = idx - start;
            start = preIdx + 1;
        }
        charPos.put(ch, idx);
    }
    return Math.max(maxLen, s.length() - start);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring(""));
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("x"));
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("xx"));
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("xxx"));
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcXdefXghiXjkl"));
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb"));
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew"));
System.out.println(lengthOfLongestSubstring("ABDEFGABEF"));
```

*Output (with candidate lists)*

```
[]: 0
[x]: 1
[x, x]: 1
[x, x, x]: 1
[abcXdef, defXghi, ghiXjkl]: 7
[abc, bca, cab, abc]: 3
[wke, kew]: 3
[ABDEFG, BDEFGA, DEFGAB]: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `ans` to the current char when a character match is found

```
ans = "" + s.charAt(i);
```

You should add the current char to all the characters after the first match of the current char

```
ans = ans.substring(ans.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) + 1) + s.charAt(i);
```

The full method thus becomes

```
    public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        String ans = "";
        int len = 0;
        LinkedList<String> substrings = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!ans.contains("" + s.charAt(i))) {
                ans += s.charAt(i);
            } else {
                substrings.add(ans);
                // Only the below line changed
                ans = ans.substring(ans.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) + 1) + s.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        substrings.add(ans); // add last seen substring into the linked list

        for (int i = 0; i < substrings.size(); i++) {
            if (substrings.get(i).length() >= len)
                len = substrings.get(i).length();
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(substrings.toArray()));

        return len;
    }
```

Using this code the acceptance criteria you specified passed successfully

```
//correct
lengthOfLongestSubstring("dvdf") -> 3 ( [dv, vdf]) 
lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb") -> 3 ([abc, bca, cab, abc, cb, b]) 
lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew") -> 3 ([pw, wke, kew]).
lengthOfLongestSubstring("ABDEFGABEF"); -> 6 ([ABDEFG, BDEFGA, DEFGAB, FGABE, GABEF])
lengthOfLongestSubstring("acadf"); -> 4 ([ac, cadf])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a nested for loop to check at each index in the array.

```
    public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {    
    String ans = "";
    int len = 0;
    LinkedList<String> substrings = new LinkedList<String>();
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(k == s.length()) {
            break;
        }
        for(k = i; k < s.length(); k++) {
          if (!ans.contains("" + s.charAt(k))) {
            ans += s.charAt(k);
          } else {
            substrings.add(ans);
            ans = "";
            break;
          }
        }
    }

    substrings.add(ans); // add last seen substring into the linked list

    for (int i = 0; i < substrings.size(); i++) {
      if (substrings.get(i).length() >= len)
        len = substrings.get(i).length();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(substrings.toArray()));

    return len;

}
```

Example:

```
lengthOfLongestSubstring("ABDEFGABEF"); -> 6 ([ABDEFG, BDEFGA, DEFGAB, EFGAB, FGABE, GABEF])
```